# Excel JS api - listen for a worksheet rename

Tags: excel, office-js

Curious if there's an event that's fired when a worksheet is renamed. Haven't found anything in the API reference, but maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Office JS Excel API currently doesn't support worksheet.onRenamed event. So, I would suggest that you could submit the request and upvote this request at [uservoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback?category_id=163563)

But there is a workaround approach that you could have a try: track the events at worksheet collection. Listen the onActivated event, store a reference to the active sheet as well as its name. When the sheet is onDeactivated(and another activated) compare the name of the sheet reference against the stored string.

---

Update 2021:
This feature is currently available in the [preview version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.worksheetcollection?view=excel-js-preview#onNameChanged) of the Excel JavaScript API.

Comment: Hi @Nils Ruckmann, I followed the documentation link which you provided and found "onNameChanged" event we can use for same. Could you please confirm this event listener is available in production, I mean can we use it now?